# ShareThis setting properties in callback don't work

Tags: url, properties, callback, sharethis

I'm using the ShareThis widget.  I need to change the url property after the object has been created so I'm using the callback function option.  In the callback function, I attempt to change the url property but the email that goes out still contains the old value.

Has anyone been able to solve this problem?  If so, I would appreciate your help!

Here's a code sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      SHARETHIS.addEntry({
          title: 'ShareThis'},
    { onclick: myCustomCallback }

      function myCustomCallback(SharedObject) {

        SharedObject.properties.url = "http://www.myurl.com";
        return true;
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the URL dynamically. If you want to do something funky, you'll need to create a new button with the new URL. This can be accomplished a few ways, the simplest being creating an element to contain the button and trigger creation of a custom button element every time something happens that should trigger the URL change.

I can show you a sample implementation that we put together for HP a few weeks ago. They actually call the "share" function from inside a Flash movie, but this prototype triggers it from a button.

You can reach me at sragan@sharethis.com

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if your solution here would help with my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036133/how-do-i-trigger-a-sharethis-button-regen

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('span[class^="st_"]').html(''); // Empty span contents

$('span[class^="st_"]').attr('st_processed',null); // Reset ST plugin

$('span[class^="st_"]').attr('st_url',url); // Set new url

stButtons.makeButtons(); // Renew buttons
```