# How do I trigger a sharethis button regen?

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I'm changing some of the properties of the sharethis button dynamically, and am looking to cause it to regen. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

depends on the customization you want to do, but if you're just dynamically adding a sharethis button, call

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

That will re-run the init code an the sharethis js will do it's magic again.